# Qt C++ emit из потока, слота в mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Есть слот в основном классе mainwindow, который выводит данные в `QTextBrowser`:

```
void MainWindow::setLogs(QString param, QString text) {
  qDebug()<<text;
  ui->Logs->append(text);
}
```

Есть класс, который запускается в отдельном потоке, делает POST-запрос и должен вставить полученные данные в `QTextBrowser`:

```
QNetworkRequest request(apiUrl);

request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0");
request.setRawHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
request.setRawHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

reply = manager.post(request, "data="+data);

connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished,this, &MakePost::getReplyFinished);
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &MakePost::readyReadReply);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(GetError()));

void MakePost::readyReadReply()
{
  QString GetRes = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
  qDebug() << "GetRes: " + GetRes;
  emit SendLog(GetRes);
}
```

Вызов потока:

```
QThread *postThread = new QThread;
MakePost *sendPost = new MakePost();
sendPost->SetParam(Data, SubUrl, requestString);

sendPost->moveToThread(postThread);
sendPost->manager.moveToThread(postThread);
connect(postThread, SIGNAL(started()), sendPost, SLOT(MakePostSignal()));
postThread->start();
```

и связка слот-поток в mainwindow:

```
connect(SendPost, SIGNAL(SendLog(QString)), this, SLOT(setLogs(QString)));
```

без потока все отрабатывает нормально, если же запускаю в потоке получают только результат `qDebug() << "GetRes: " + GetRes;` и все...

Подскажите, как правильно создать конструкцию сигнал-слот между потоком - главным окном?

Comment: У Вас слот объявлен   
'void MainWindow::setLogs(QString param, QString text)'  
а в строке connect(...) вы написали 'setLogs(QString)'  
Это и в одном потоке не должно работать.  
Количество и тип параметров, должно быть одинаково в объявлении слота в объявлении сигнала и соответственно при вызове connect(...)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас слот объявлен.

```
 void MainWindow::setLogs(QString param, QString text)
```

а в строке connect(...) вы написали.

```
setLogs(QString)
```

Это и в одном потоке не должно работать. Количество и тип параметров, должно быть одинаково в объявлении слота в объявлении сигнала и соответственно при вызове connect(...)